# Facing issues in upgrading rails version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When I run bundle install it shows :

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
You have requested:
  rails = 4.2.1

The bundle currently has rails locked at 4.1.0.
Try running `bundle update rails`
```

Then I run: `bundle update rails`
It gives:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    devise (>= 0) ruby depends on
      responders (>= 0) ruby depends on
        railties (< 4.2, >= 3.2) ruby

    rails (= 4.2.1) ruby depends on
      railties (4.2.1)
```

Please help me out in solving this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: delete your `gemfile.lock` file and run `bundle`

Comment: Done that but after that I am facing `An error occurred while installing libv8 (3.16.14.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that ` `gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.7'`` succeeds before bundling.`

Comment: install `libv8 -v '3.16.14.7'` gem

Comment: Thanx it works after removing gemfile.lock run bundle install and install `gem install  libv8 -v '3.16.14.7'`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using an older version of devise--you'll need to update your devise version to work with Rails 4.2 (`bundle update devise`).  Once devise is updated to 3.4.x, it can use railties v4.2.1.